# Apache: Mod_security causing 404, unless i clear the cookies every session

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-security, mod-security2

I installed `mod_security` on my apache and ubunto14 server and it works, it's enabled.
but my website started acting weird, throwing 404 errors
then after some suggestions found on the web I cleared the cache & cookie and everything worked. until the next page reload.

what am i doing wrong? what else do i need to setup for the server to work correctly?

thanks

Comment: See here: http://serverfault.com/questions/759633/mod-security-too-strict-rule/760240#760240